# Get JSONArray without Arrayname in method

Tags: java, android, json, vuforia

I need to get JSONArray from my data in string but without mentioning the arrayname as follows. It should get Array name itself from JSON data.

Here is my code

```
            String metadata = result.getMetaData();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(metadata);

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Shoe2");

              for(int i =0 ; i<jsonArray.length();++i) {
                JSONObject rec = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                barcode = rec.getString("BarcodeId");
                material=rec.getString("Material");
                category=rec.getString("Category");

            }
            Baroode.setText(barcode);
            Material.setText(material);
            Category.setText(category);
```

Now what I need is get JSON arrayname "SHoes1" by itself rather than use explicit naming as I am doing so.

My JSON String looks like this

```
{
"Shoe2":[{
           "BarcodeId" : "9770012345673",
            "   " : "Men",
            "Material" : "Panther",
            "ProductId" : "ND-TR-0089",
            "ProductName" : "Black Retro"
        }
    ]
}
```

Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: You want to get "sheos1" without naming it?

Comment: You can get the whole body in json,, but if you want a specific array you should name the header

Comment: What looks like your json string? Please provide your code as [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry shoes2 is what I need without naming it. @BitaMirshafiee

Comment: basically what my app does is it scans a image and after scan I get a string with the metadata which is in the format of json. It is not conveniant for me to explicitly name each array as I am doing here. @BitaMirshafiee

Comment: @EmreSavcı posted my json data

Comment: Do you have only one array in your root of json?

Comment: Yes. Just one with "Shoe2" name, but dont want to specify it explicitly as I am doing it currently. The app should get arrayName itself from using JSONArray and return me the values of barcodeID,Material as I am doing it.@EmreSavcı

Comment: Just one more question to clerify, is your json contains only one key in the root object or there are other properties after your array `Shoe2`?

Comment: Where is `"SHoes1"`?

Comment: @EmreSavcı only one key "Shoe2"

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have your json in a file name test.json. If you have your array as first element of your root json you can access it via the code below :

```
package yourPackage;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String metadata = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.json")));
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(metadata);

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(jsonObject.keys().next().toString());

        System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0));
    }
}
```

Output :

```
{"   ":"Men","ProductName":"Black Retro","Material":"Panther","ProductId":"ND-TR-0089","BarcodeId":"9770012345673"}
```

test.json :

```
{
  "Shoe2":[{
    "BarcodeId" : "9770012345673",
    "   " : "Men",
    "Material" : "Panther",
    "ProductId" : "ND-TR-0089",
    "ProductName" : "Black Retro"
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am using android studio for coding. The method .keySet() is not working ?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. `keySet()` not works on android it should be `keys()`.